# How do I effectively clear a buffer in Java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, buffer, do-while

This is a method for the main class of this problem.

I have an issue when the user inputs a non-numeric value for the requested information.

Example)

```
Enter a distance in meters: jam
Incorrect value. Please select a distance in meters greater than zero.

Enter a distance in meters: Incorrect value. Please select a distance greater than zero. 

Enter a distance in meters:
```

This is the output that occurs when this method is called. How do i correct this?

```
public static double validDistance (String prompt,
                                    double minValue) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    double value;
    String errorMessage = "Incorrect value. Please select a distance in "
            + "meters greater than zero\n";
    // Protects distance input from incorrect value 
    // (non-numeric or too low)
    do {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
            value = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if (value <= minValue) {
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
            } else {
                break; // Exit loop
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            keyboard.nextLine(); // Clears buffer
        }
    } while (true);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: You need to loop the prompt and input.

Comment: Move `keyboard.nextLine();` outside the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question.

I personally find that dealing with the `Scanner` buffer is incredibly annoying, so I prefer just reading line by line and doing the processing myself. For example:

```
public static double validDistance(String prompt, double minValue)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String errorMessage = "Incorrect value. Please select a distance in meters greater than zero\n";
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        try {
            double result = Double.parseDouble(line);
            if (result >= minValue) {
                keyboard.close(); // You should always close a Scanner when you're done!
                return result;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
    }
}
```